# How do I get this block of code to keep looping until a correct student number is entered?

Tags: java, while-loop

How would I get this code to keep on asking for "student number" until a student number is entered correctly starting with the character 'X' and then continue on with the program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SDevCA2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        //inputs
        //Option 1


        String userName;
        String passWord1;
        String passWord2;
        String eol;
        String userInput;
        int loopVal =0;
        char firstLetter = 'X';
        int userOption;
        final double FULLGRANT = 3000;
        final double GRANTSEVENTYFIVE = 2250;
        final double GRANTFIFTY = 1500;

        double softWareGrade =0;
        double mathsGrade =0;
        double systemGrade =0;
        double computerArchGrade =0;


        double gradeCount;
        final double SUBJECT_COUNT = 4;

        double averageGrade;
        int overallAverageResults;
        int feesOwedPercent;
        double feesOwedEuros;

        //Option 2

        double feesPaidByGrant =0;
        double feesNotPaidByGrant =0;
        int totalStudentsProcessed =0;
        int totalStudentsRecievedGrant =0;

        //Option 3

        int studentsWith100Paid =0;
        int studentsWith75Paid =0;
        int studentsWith50Paid =0;
        int studentsWithNoGrant =0;

        int categoryMostStudents;

        //End of Inputs
        boolean run = true;
        while ( run ) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

         //input of data
        //input of data

       System.out.println("Please enter your username: ");
       userName = in.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
       passWord1  = in.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Please re-enter your password: ");
       passWord2  = in.nextLine();
       while (!passWord1.equals(passWord2))
        {

       System.out.println("Incorrect! Please try re-entering password ");
       System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
       passWord1  = in.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Please re-enter your password: ");
       passWord2  = in.nextLine();

                    }


        //ABC Grant Menu.
        System.out.println("\n  --------------------------------");
       System.out.println ("Welcome to the ABC College Grant System  \n 1. Calculate Grant  \n 2. Fee Statistics   \n 3. Grant Category Information   \n 4. Exit");
       userOption = in.nextInt();


        //if Invalid Entry Error Message with the ABC Menu again



        //Option 1 
       switch ( userOption ) {
            case 1:


       String studentName;
       String studentNumber;         



       System.out.println ("Please Enter your Student Name: ");
       studentName = in.next();




       System.out.println ("Please Enter your Student Number: ");
       userInput = in.next();

       while ( userInput.charAt(0) == firstLetter) {
       System.out.println("Correct");
       break;

       }

       while ( userInput.charAt(0) != firstLetter)
       {


        System.out.println("No match, Student Numbr must begin with character capital X ");
       }   






       {





           //Error message if Student Number doesn't start with X

           System.out.println ("What was your Grade in Software Development");
           softWareGrade = in.nextDouble();

           System.out.println ("What was your Grade in Maths");
           mathsGrade = in.nextDouble ();

           System.out.println("What was your Grade in Systems Analasys");
           systemGrade = in.nextDouble ();

           System.out.println("What was your Grade in Computer Archetecture");
           computerArchGrade = in.nextDouble();


           //Formula

           gradeCount = softWareGrade + mathsGrade + systemGrade + computerArchGrade;
           averageGrade = gradeCount / SUBJECT_COUNT;

           //100% FEES PAID





           if (averageGrade >=80 && averageGrade <=100) {
               feesOwedPercent = 0;
               feesOwedEuros = 0;
               totalStudentsProcessed ++;
               totalStudentsRecievedGrant ++;
               studentsWith100Paid ++;
               feesPaidByGrant = feesPaidByGrant + FULLGRANT;
               System.out.println ("Student Name: " + studentName);
               System.out.println ("Student Number: " + userInput);
               System.out.println ("Average Grade: " +averageGrade);
               System.out.println("Fees Owed: " +feesOwedPercent);
               System.out.println("Fees not paid " + feesOwedEuros);

           }

           if  (averageGrade >=60 && averageGrade <80 ) {
               feesOwedPercent = 25;
               feesOwedEuros = 750;
               totalStudentsProcessed ++;
               totalStudentsRecievedGrant ++;
               studentsWith75Paid ++;
               feesPaidByGrant = feesPaidByGrant + GRANTSEVENTYFIVE;
               feesNotPaidByGrant = feesNotPaidByGrant + feesOwedEuros;
               System.out.println ("Student Name: " + studentName);
               System.out.println ("Student Number: " + userInput);
               System.out.println ("Average Grade" +averageGrade);
               System.out.println("Fees Owed: " +feesOwedPercent);
               System.out.println("Fees not paid " + feesOwedEuros );
           }

           if   (averageGrade >=40 && averageGrade <60) {
               feesOwedPercent = 50;
               feesOwedEuros = 1500;
               totalStudentsProcessed ++;
               totalStudentsRecievedGrant ++;
               studentsWith50Paid ++;
               feesPaidByGrant = feesPaidByGrant + GRANTFIFTY;
               feesNotPaidByGrant = feesNotPaidByGrant + feesOwedEuros;
               System.out.println ("Student Name: " + studentName);
               System.out.println ("Student Number: " + userInput);
               System.out.println ("Average Grade" +averageGrade);
               System.out.println("Fees Owed: " +feesOwedPercent);
               System.out.println("Fees not paid " + feesOwedEuros );


           }

           if ( averageGrade <40 ) {
               feesOwedPercent = 100;
               feesOwedEuros = 3000;
               totalStudentsProcessed ++;
               studentsWithNoGrant ++;
               feesNotPaidByGrant = feesNotPaidByGrant + feesOwedEuros;
               System.out.println ("Student Name: " + studentName);
               System.out.println ("Student Number: " + userInput);
               System.out.println ("Average Grade" +averageGrade);
               System.out.println("Fees Owed: " +feesOwedPercent);
               System.out.println("Fees not paid " + feesOwedEuros );
               break;

       }

                switch ( userOption) {
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("The overall fess paid by the grant: €" +feesPaidByGrant );
                        System.out.println("The overall fees not paid by the grant: €" +feesNotPaidByGrant );
                        System.out.println("The total number of students processed is: " +totalStudentsProcessed );
                        System.out.println("The total number of students who recieved a grant is: " +totalStudentsRecievedGrant );
                        break;

    }
                switch ( userOption ) {
                    case 3:
                        System.out.print("How many stduents are given grants in the following catergory");
                        System.out.println("100% Paid: " +studentsWith100Paid );
                        System.out.println("75% Paid: " +studentsWith75Paid );
                        System.out.println("50% Paid: " +studentsWith50Paid );
                        System.out.println("No Grant Paid: " +studentsWithNoGrant );
                        break;
                }

                switch ( userOption) {
                    case 4: 
                        System.out.print("The number of stduents that are given grants in the following catergories: ");
                        System.out.println("\n");
                        System.out.println("100% Paid: " +studentsWith100Paid );
                        System.out.println("75% Paid: " +studentsWith75Paid );
                        System.out.println("50% Paid: " +studentsWith50Paid );
                        System.out.println("No Grant Paid: " +studentsWithNoGrant );

                        System.out.print("\n");
                        System.out.print("\n");
                        System.out.print("The catergory from which most grants are paid is: ");





                        run=false;
                        break;
                    default:
                }

    }
    }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: like you did it in your code: while ( userInput.charAt(0) != firstLetter)
   {


    System.out.println("No match, Student Numbr must begin with character capital X ");
   }

Comment: Yes, but how do we get it to keep on asking until they enter something with 'X' and then continue with the rest of the program

Comment: what do you think will happen when the user there enters something that starts with the same char as firstLetter ? then it'll continue, just as you ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for prompting the user for their student number and then accepting their input must be inside your while loop. Try something like this:

```
boolean validNumber = false;
while (!validNumber) {
  System.out.println ("Please Enter your Student Number: ");
  userInput = in.next();

  if (userInput.charAt(0) == firstLetter) {
    validNumber = true;
  } else {
     System.out.println("No match, Student Numbr must begin with character capital X ");
  }
}
```

Comment: with a do while loop, you could get rid of more than half those lines of code.

Comment: Absolutely, there's a few optimisations that could be made. I wrote it like this purely for the sake of clarity and because I don't know how much of the language the OP is familiar with, so this just uses the same features used in the question. Good suggestion though :)

Comment: But keep in mind you have to declare the variables you check in your do-while condition before you enter the loop itself.

Comment: Yeah, I see where you are coming from but cannot seem to get this working been working on this program a while now and need it done in the next two hours.. Now the switch case statements are acting up

Comment: What exactly can you not get working? You should be able to just copy and paste the code above into your program.  Specifically it should take the place of this code-
       System.out.println ("Please Enter your Student Number: ");
       userInput = in.next();

       while ( userInput.charAt(0) == firstLetter) {
       System.out.println("Correct");
       break;

       }

       while ( userInput.charAt(0) != firstLetter)
       {


        System.out.println("No match, Student Numbr must begin with character capital X ");
       }

Comment: Also, if you have a problem with your switch statement, please put that in another question and I'll be glad to take a look :)

Comment: After I enter the username and password and then choose calculate grant which is case 1 it is working but when choosing case 2,3 or 4 its asking for username and password again and looping the program menu instead of whats in the cases

Comment: ok, two things. First of all, take the code in each of your cases and move the into a separate method (except the break statement, leave that in the case). This will make the code much more readable which will help you to spot any issues. Secondly, and this may be the cause of your bug, you have a switch statement before each case. This is not necessary. You only need one switch, then you list each case inside of that. This link has some reasonable examples - http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/switch-statement/java-switch-case-example/